# Joined tables in admin form

Tags: magento2, database, admin, grid, adminform

I have two tables, one for a list of poll questions and another for the answers to a specific poll. I want to be able to display the list of questions in a grid, then save the question and the answers together in an admin form.

I know how to join the tables together, but when I do, in the grid, the lines are duplicated for each corresponding answer. Also, I can't edit them and get the error `item with same id already exists`.

Here is my join :

```
public function _construct(){
    $this->_init("Vendor\Module\Model\Poll","Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Poll");
}

protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('poll_answers')],
            'main_table.PollId = secondTable.PollId',
            ['AnswerId','AnswerText']
        )->group('main_table.PollId'); //EDIT
    $this->addFilterToMap('PollId', 'main_table.PollId');
}
```

Are joins actually the way to go for this problem ?

EDIT : I can use the `group` function on my select to remove the duplicates inside my grid, but that prevents me from getting all the answers in my form. How can I get around that ?